# How can I refactor this code for LINQ filtering?

Tags: c#, linq

Using DataTables (Table plug-in for jQuery) with server side processing I had to create filtering for my data with good performance. I did it however in my opinion it's kinda ugly. A especially part of (`.Where(...)`) where I have to compare manually each property with `search` variable. Is it possible to make it better?

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic; // because of special .OrderBy

public class SomeRepository
{
    public DataTableDTO GetAllFromBase(int start, int length, string sortColumn, string sortColumnDir, string search)
    {
        var dataFiltered = db.User
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.Description})
            .OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir)
            .Where(search.Length > 0, x => x.Id.ToString().Contains(search.ToLower())
                                        || x.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                                        || x.LastName.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                                        || x.Description.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()));

        var recordsFiltered = dataFiltered.Count();
        var recordsTotal = db.User.Count();

        var dataToShow = dataFiltered
            .Skip(start)
            .Take(length)
            .ToList();

        var dataForTable = new DataTableDTO
        {
            Data = dataToShow,
            RecordsTotal = recordsTotal,
            RecordsFiltered = recordsFiltered
        };

        return dataForTable;
    }
}

public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, bool condition, Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereClause)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            return query.Where(whereClause);
        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should write this in codereview- > http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok I didn't know, thank you :)

Comment: Does it find John Smith if you type "John Smith"?? It looks like you'll find all the Johns if you search for "John" all the Smiths if you search for "Smith" but what happens when you search for both first and last name? Looks like the where clause doesn't handle this because "John Smith" is neither in the first name or last name column.

Comment: I wanted to search only by one field. If the other fields contains "John", it's still fine. For example, if I would have two records: `1. John Smith` and `2. Mike John` then is fine to display both of them when I lookin for "John". It was the point.

Comment: Few comments because you mentioned performance. AFAIK Entity Framework is one of the slowest ways to query data. Seems like your code is making 3 separate queries to the database for `recordsFiltered`, `recordsTotal`, and `dataForTable`. I would recommend using a database stored procedure if possible for just one call to the database and avoiding the Entity Framework overhead.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract this method:

```
public bool SearchForMatching(string source, string serach)
{
    return source.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower());
}
```

It will Simplify your Where clause:

```
Where(x => SearchForMatching(x.Id, search)
           || SearchForMatching(x.FirstName, search)
           || SearchForMatching(x.LastName, search)
           || SearchForMatching(x.Description, search));
```

Another option if you don't want to search for every property one by one and you want to check if any of the class's propeties answers the search is to use reflection to iterate over the class's properties and check if there is any one that answers the condition:

```
public bool SearchForMatching(User user, string search)
{
    return user.GetType().GetPropeties().Any(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(user).ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()));
}
```

Then use this method in the Where clause:

```
Where(x => SearchForMatching(x, search));
```

Or just combine them together:

```
Where(x => x.GetType().GetPropeties().Any(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(x).ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()));
```

**Edit**
The two options should work just fine with LINQ to Objects but it will probably not collaborate well with LINQ to Entities because it is not possible to translate neither the first option or the reflection option to SQL using LINQ to Entities.
You can load all the data to memeory using db.User.AsEnumerable() and then work with LINQ to Objects with any of these options, but it is less efficient than doing all the filtering in the database like your first query does, I suggest you despite it's readblity to keep your first query.

Comment: I can't add there operator `&&` because I expecting all records when search is empty. The rest looks fine, I'll check this

Comment: @DiPix added another option, you should check it.

Comment: When I'm trying to make `var recordsFiltered = dataFiltered.Count();` I have an error: `Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean SearchForMatching(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression`